# Returning a pointer from a member function of a class

Tags: c++, libxml2

My code looks something like this:

xmlparser.h file:

```
#include <libxml++/libxml++.h>  
#include <iostream>
using namspace std, xmlpp;

class xmlpar {  
    public:
         xmlparse(){}
         ~xmlparse(){}
         const Node* root_node();
};
```

xmlparser.cc file:

```
#include "xmlparser.h"
const Node* xmlpar::root_node() {
    const Node* rnode;
    DomParser parser;
    parser.parse_file("sample.xml");
    if (parser) {
       rnode = parser.get->document()->get_root_node();
       cout << rnode->get_name(); // prints "component" as in xml file
       return rnode;
    }
 }
```

My main.cc file:

```
#include "xmlparser.h"
int main() {
    xmlparser par;
    const Node* root = par.root_node();
    cout << root->get_name(); // prints "PQ". --> Problem location
}
```

I first compiled the xmlparser.cc file, then the main.cc, and then created an executable with both main.o and xmlparser.o . I'm not getting any error during compilation but Like in the code if I'm returning rnode from the method root_node(), the values of the root
gets changed to something like "PQ" instead of "component". Can anyone please tell me what's happening here and the solution to the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know `libxml2`, but it seems like you return pointer to a local object.

```
DomParser parser;
```

in `const Node* xmlpar::root_node()` is a local object. Then you do what you do and finally

```
rnode = parser.get->document()->get_root_node();
```

which makes `rnode` to point to some place in the document. You return pointer to it, but after the end of the function (after it returns), the `parser` is destroyed, as it's local object.

This makes the returned pointer invalid and you have **undefined behavior**

Comment: A solution to the problem would be to make the `parser` variable into a member variable of the class instead of being local to the function. This would also be better if more nodes need to be fetched later from the same XML file.

Comment: True. Or too have 2 out parameters and allocate the parser using `new`. Then use the 2 out parameters to return the allocated parser and the `rnode`. Or just return pointer to the parser.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `rnode` is a local variable, and stored on the stack. So when `xmlpar::root_node` returns the variable doesn't exist any more.

You can fix it by declaring `rnode` to be `static`.

Comment: This is about as incorrect as in answer can be, I am afraid.  The cause is the `DomParser` being local.

Comment: +1. I would also suggest to move parser a rnode to be a members of a class (private, public, doesn't matter)

Comment: @Moo-Juice: My bad. Still too early here it seems. Kirils answer is better.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I removed my -1 because you're in Malmo.  I feel your pain.

Comment: -1. Returning pointers by value is perfectly ok. The problem is with the pointee, not the pointer.